# API for Android/iPhone app towards database and Oauth 2

Tags: php, android, ios, database

My client wants an Android app and an iPhone app. Is it a good solution to make a PHP based API that both of these apps can use to talk to the server.The API will be used to access the database and to authorisera through OAuth and some other non-database functionality.

Will there be an significant performance loss with an API instead of a direct connection to the database?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problems with PHP, which, in general, isn't really good in handling a few hundred connections at the some time. Anyway, I would highly recommend you to use some sort of API which filters the input it receives instead of letting anyone connect to the database, otherwise it might be empty within the first few hours of your apps launch (aka this is a HUGE security risk!).

Comment: I agree with what you say. Safety is priority. Should I use another language, then you mention that php is not preferable?

Comment: @user1195745 I didn't said that PHP isn't preferable. Like always, the choice of languages depends on what exactly you want to achieve.